How to determine if a pseudo console is waiting for user input?
The pseudo console in question is created using winapi::um::consoleapi::CreatePseudoConsole
I've tried determining if its waiting for input by scraping the output. But.. that is unreliable, to say the least.
I also tried seeing if the output pipe buffer is empty to determine if its waiting for input. But that is also unreliable, because when using yielding commands (such as ping), the buffer will be empty for a bit because of latency.

It might be a good idea to use the official windows crate instead of some third party bindings. Though I don't see how to query for the state of a pseudo console there either.

I'm not sure what you want is possible in the first place. I think you cannot check if the app is actively waiting for input as much as you cannot check if a remote system is waiting for data. You only get the output and can send data to it, but not query some internal state about "waiting for input".

@SteffenUllrich I understand. Perhaps, is there any behavior in the state of the pipes that could indicate the console is waiting for input? Such as, I dont know, a pipe being blocked.

There is not. A console accepts user input at all times. The concept of "waiting for user input (before making forward progress again)" is exclusively implemented in the application connected to a console.
